# Catlina.out not showing logger message

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j, tomcat6

I am using log4j to print the log using java but my log messages not visible in catlina.out file bello is my .properties file

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

ConsoleAppender logs to the console. So you should use another appender, for example, FileAppender.